# Why are C array elements (seemingly) stored in blocks of 4?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, memory-address

I'm just learning C and getting my head around pointers. It's my understanding that when you declare an array, the address of the array is the address of the first element in that array. All other elements are stored contiguously in memory.

When I ran this code using the [online C compiler at onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) ...

```
int main()
{
    int num[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("num[%d] has the value %d and is stored at address %p\n",
               i, num[i], &num[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I observed the following ...

```
num[0] has the value 0 and is stored at address 0x7ffe9973e600
num[1] has the value 1 and is stored at address 0x7ffe9973e604
num[2] has the value 2 and is stored at address 0x7ffe9973e608
num[3] has the value 3 and is stored at address 0x7ffe9973e60c
num[4] has the value 4 and is stored at address 0x7ffe9973e610
```

So from what I can see, the C compiler picks a memory location for `num[0]`, and then every subsequent element is placed four addresses away. I'm aware that every compiler could be different and have a different behaviour, but in case this is standard - why are array elements seemingly stored in blocks of four? Why doesn't the address pattern go `0x7ffe9973e600`, `...601`, `...602`, `...603`, `...604`? Does each element take up more than one address?

Comment: Because `int` has 4 bytes? (Please note that `int` has __at least__ 16 bits, so it may happen on a different platform that `int` has 2 bytes. Or 8 bytes)

Comment: Oh ... yeah, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: The first chapters of any C programming book typically addresses numerical limits of the various integer types and thereby how large they can be.

Comment: Each element of the array of `int` uses up `sizeof(int)` addressable memory locations. (The C standard calls an addressable memory location a "byte" no matter how many bits it has.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address in memory represent the data for 1 byte. The `num` array is of `int` type which takes 4 bytes each. So to store one element `num[0]` we need to occupy 4 bytes of memory and since each byte require 1 memory address thus they have a gap of 4 memory addresses. If it were a `char` array then you would see the sequence 0x7ffe9973e600, ...601, ...602, ...603, ...604 and so on.

Comment: Great, short and sweet explanation. Thanks! It's my first time dealing with memory directly and thinking about how much space different data types take up, so while this probably seems obvious to anyone else, your explanation really helps :).

Comment: Keep learning. Pointers are confusing at first but once you get a hang of them, they are good. Anyways if it answers your question, do hit an accept on it